# Changing to $\frac00$ form

Tags: calculus

Given a and b are two positive constants and the following equation. Find
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{bx^3-x^2e\sin x}{\sqrt{a+2x^5}}= \frac{1}{π}$$

Have to use L'Hôpital's rule, but have no idea to change the denominator to be 0.

Comment: What makes you think you should use L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: I have changed your limit to be more readable. please look through it and see that it is made right. For next time, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematics.

Comment: to have  aform 0/0 it should be $a=0$ and also $x\to 0^+$

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo? Given $a$ and $b$ are positive, the limit is 0, no L'Hopital required.

Comment: And if $a=0$ then for small $x$ it is about $\frac{b-e}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{x}$ which also has a limit of $0$ unless $b=e$

Comment: As the equation equates to \frac{1}{π} I have no idea how to progress on except using L'Hopital rule

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are positive you can't apply L'Hôpital.

Comment: @coffee Do you have a typo?

Comment: If $a=0$ and $b=e$ then for small $x$ it is about $\frac{e}{6\sqrt{2}}x^{5/2}$ which also has a limit of $0$

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for l'Hôpital, unless $a=0$. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{bx^3-x^2e\sin(x)}{\sqrt{a+2x^5}}=\frac{0}{\sqrt{a}}=0$$

Comment: It was defined that the equation equates to 1/π. I'll just have to assume that the question was wrong in this case?